# Problems Installing DBD::mysql for Perl on Sun Unix

Tags: mysql, perl

Trying to add `MySQL` to my existing Perl installation.

I am using `DBD-mysql-4.050` and then running `perl Makefile.PL`, 
but I get this **error**:

> Can't locate Devel/CheckLib.pm in @INC

Comment: Have you tried to install it? Try `cpan Devel::CheckLib`

Comment: When you do the installation manually (e.g. using `perl Makefile.PL`), you need to install the distribution's dependencies. These are usually listed in the `README` file in the distribution. Or you could simple use `cpan DBD::mysql` and let `cpan` handle those for you.

Answer (score 1):

When you do the installation manually (e.g. using `perl Makefile.PL`), you need to install the distribution's dependencies. These are usually listed in a `README*` file in the distribution (not here) and in a `META.*` file.

```
"prereqs" : {
   "configure" : {
      "requires" : {
         "DBI" : "1.609",
         "Data::Dumper" : "0",
         "Devel::CheckLib" : "1.09",
         "ExtUtils::MakeMaker" : "0"
      }
   },
   "build" : {
      "requires" : {
         "ExtUtils::MakeMaker" : "0"
      }
   },
   "test" : {
      "requires" : {
         "Test::Deep" : "0",
         "Test::Simple" : "0.90",
         "Time::HiRes" : "0",
         "bigint" : "0"
      },
      "recommends" : {
         "Proc::ProcessTable" : "0"
      },
      "suggests" : {
         "Test::DistManifest" : "0",
         "Test::Pod" : "1.00"
      }
   },
   "runtime" : {
      "requires" : {
         "DBI" : "1.609",
         "perl" : "5.008001"
      }
   }
}
```

(The numbers represent minimum versions, and the `perl` dependency refers to the version of Perl —in this case 5.8.1— rather than a module.)

Or you could simple use the following command and let `cpan` handle the dependencies for you.

```
cpan DBD::mysql
```